# Short phrase for a controller connected to something by wires

Tags: single-word-requests

If there is a mechanical device which is controlled by electronics, these electronics can be hidden inside the device itself or hang outside it and connected to it by wires. Is there a word which indicates the second option, without writing a lengthy sentence?

Example: instead of:
"... a device with a controller connected to it by wires"

something like:
"... a device with a controller *_* wires". (in wires? on wires? by wires?)

"on wires" would seem to be the logical choice to me, but I couldn't find a single relevant phrase on Google.

Comment: you could say "hanging by" wires in some cases

Comment: My PC is controlled by a mouse and keyboard (I don't think it would be very helpful if these were "hidden inside the computer"). As it happens, my "controllers" are wireless, but if they weren't, they'd be examples of ***wired** controllers*.

Answer (score 2):

how about `with an external wired controller`?

Comment: I was also about to suggest internal/external to distinguish the two possible cases. Alternatively, I remember the term "built-in" being used for such purposes.

Comment: "built-in" is somewhat unclear w.r.t. the location of the controller. It might also mean that the controller is inside the device and wired to other components in there. I'm thinking "controller chips" here.

Answer (score 0):

so, a device with visible wires

Comment: The point should be where the controller is located. Not inside, but outside, ___ wires.

Comment: right. so, a room in a victorian house has 'switches with visible wires' or 'exposed wires'.  a switch is a controller.